# Wait for Styles to be Applied when Dynamically Adding CSS Rules to Document

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a string representing a bunch of CSS rules I'd like to add to a document dynamically. Something like this would do the trick:

```
function loadCssRules(rules, doc, callback) {
  var styleElement = this.createElement("style", doc);
  styleElement.type = 'text/css';

  if (styleElement.styleSheet) {
    // IE < 11
    styleElement.styleSheet.cssText = rules;
  } else if (styleElement.sheet) {
    // IE >= 11
    styleElement.sheet.cssText = rules;
  } else {
    // Other browsers
    styleElement.innerHTML = rules;
  }

  if (callback) {
    styleElement.addEventListener('load', callback);
  }

  doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
}
```

However, `callback` would never be called. I suppose it's because the `style` element doesn't support the `load` event, isn't it?

Is there anyway I could continue execution only after all new rules have been applied?

Comment: Applying styles is synchronous, there is nothing to wait for ?

Comment: @adeneo Are you sure? Do you know if it's in the spec? Is there any way I could trigger a re-layout so I can be double sure? You see, adding those rules change the layout of the whole document and as I need to do some positioning based on the dimensions of some of the elements, having some elements having the *old* sizes would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, rules appliance are synchronous. I hope to be right, if that's the case, whis would work:

```
function loadCssRules(rules, doc, callback) {
  var styleElement = this.createElement("style", doc);
  ...    
    styleElement.innerHTML = rules;
  } 
  doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Well, if it's synchronious, there would be no need for the callback, actually... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you add style tag the browser rebuild it `stylesheet tree` and `reflow/repaint` necessary `layers`, but this don't block `user I/O` where does javascript executes. So styles and scripts will apply async.

But if you will change size of any DOM elements in stylesheet rules javascript will be [blocked](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_order_of_processing_scripts_and_style_sheets) while browser engine recalculate new size.